# Pass a return value from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have 3 files main.php, action.js and ajax.php and i successfully changed the content on click of some divs from main.php to some of ajax.php with a ajax call in my javascript file. It looks like this:

```
var value = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {
        auto_value: value
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('.gridnr1, .textnr1').fadeOut(400, function(){
            $('.textnr2, .gridnr2').fadeIn(400);
        });

        var newtextcaption = $(response).filter('#newtextcaption').html();
        var box = $(response).filter('#box').html();

        $('#textnr2').html(newtextcaption);
        $('#gridnr2').html(box);

        for (var i=0; i<VALUE_FROM_AJAXphp; i++) {
            DO SOMETHING WITH i;
        }
    });
```

Now i need a return value from a function in ajax.php in my action.js because I want to iterate till this value (see the code above).
How to pass this value from the ajax.php to the action.js.
I am confused what do I need to get the value ajax?, json? or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Your braces aren't properly matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the success function, response, is what you get back from the PHP. so sending JSON would be easiest, because then your response is just an object.

Lets say ajax.php returns this JSON

```
{
    "newtextcaption": "whatever the text is",
    "boxhtml": "whatever your box html is",
    "AjaxValue": 4389489473289
}
```

then your success function should be

```
 success: function(response) {
                $('.gridnr1, .textnr1').fadeOut(400, function(){
                    $('.textnr2, .gridnr2').fadeIn(400);
                });

                var newtextcaption = response.newtextcaption;
                var box = response.boxhtml;

                $('#textnr2').html(newtextcaption);
                $('#gridnr2').html(box);

                for (var i=0; i<response.AjaxValue; i++) {
                     DO SOMETHING WITH i;
                }
```